# cov-build compilation errors with golang 1.19

Tags: go, coverity

I'm running a scan of a golang project but I face unexpected compilation errors.
In the summary there is a note preventing successful submission:

```
[WARNING] Emitted 2417 Go compilation units (58%) successfully
2023-01-04T15:54:36.295634Z|cov-build|7|info|> 2417 Go compilation units (58%) are ready for analysis
```

Here is the process of building:

```
cov-configure --comptype go --compiler /usr/local/go/bin/go
cov-build --dir cov-int bash -c 'GOOS=linux make build'
```

The make target includes `go mod download` and `go build` commands.
In the logs there are many errors from the compilation of imported dependencies like:

```
[STATUS] Compiling file /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/kubectl@v0.25.2/pkg/cmd/util/printing.go
[ERROR] Basic type unimplemented: invalid type
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/linux64-packages/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x65
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateFile.func1({0xd8fed8, 0xc048893ef0})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:327 +0x8c
panic({0xc5d240, 0xc04e06ba50})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/linux64-packages/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1038 +0x215
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateBasic(0x4900000000cfd2c0, 0x2)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:5952 +0x51e
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateType(0x1335560, {0xd83578, 0x13356a0})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:5683 +0x205
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateCastExpression(0xc00044a140, {0x7f0bbc0dbe30, 0xc0488a0340}, {0xd83578, 0x1335560}, {0xd83578, 0x13356a0}, 0x0, 0x0)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:1362 +0x79
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateCallExpr(0xc00044a140, 0xc02fa22180)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:1602 +0xf85
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateExpr(0xc00044a140, {0xd83b88, 0xc02fa22180})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:757 +0x1af
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateCallExpr(0xc00044a140, 0xc02fa221c0)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:1633 +0xa38
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateExpr(0xc00044a140, {0xd83b88, 0xc02fa221c0})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:757 +0x1af
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateReturnStmt(0xc00044a140, 0xd6ad88, {0xd8f4a8, 0xc0488a0030})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:2728 +0x4e9
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateStmt(0xc048703040, {0xd84098, 0xc032698140}, {0xd8f4a8, 0xc0488a0030})
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:2611 +0x4ea
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateFuncBody(0xc00044a140, 0xc033bbc6f0, 0xc022e3d4a0, 0x0, 0xc033bbc6c0)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:4935 +0x691
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateFuncDecl(0xc00044a140, 0xc033bbc720)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:721 +0x42a
main.(*AstEmitter).xlateFile(0xc00044a140, 0xc02d8f0a80)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:343 +0x3e5
main.(*AstEmitter).xlatePackage(0xc00044a140, 0xc0009d4f00)
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/ast-emitter.go:274 +0x4e5
main.main()
        /data00/jenkins/workspace/SAT/prevent-2022.6.linux64/build/frontend/cov-emit-go/cov-internal-go-fe/src/cov-internal-go-fe/cov-internal-go-fe.go:165 +0xc25
```

There are no compilation errors outside of cov-build tool.

There is used golang1.19. Could it be that coverity doesn't support golang1.19 or there is some configuration missing?
There is used Coverity scanning tool 2022.6.0.

I tried also adding command found in some posts:
`cov-configure --template --compiler go-module --comptype go-module`
but with the same compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed is most likely that the Go version is not supported.  The [Coverity 2022.6.0: Supported Platforms, Languages, and Compilers](https://sig-docs.synopsys.com/polaris/topics/r_coverity-compatible-platforms_2022.6.html) page says it supports "Go 1.16–1.17", and:

> Build capture requires that your project use a compiler version which is supported by Polaris.

As the error message ("Basic type unimplemented: invalid type") implies that some basic type is invalid, Coverity is almost certainly choking on a basic type added after Go 1.17.

I speculate it is related to the [addition of generics](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#generics) in Go 1.18, support for which will require substantial changes in tools like Coverity.